# Find occurrences where there is a number-number (5-10) in regex

Tags: python, regex

I need to find occurrences where there is a number followed by a hyphen and another number.
eg. 5-10,6-12

```
ExampleString ="a5-10b,48-99z, 6-12, 5-9 ,4-2"
vals =  re.findall(r'(\s\d+\s?)-(\s?\d+\s?)' ,ExampleString)
```

I need the vals to capture 6-12, 5-9 ,4-2.
I am finding it hard to capture only the numbers without the 48-99z. if I remove the question mark in the last \s? it does not capture 4-2 and if I keep it,  it captures 48-99z(which I dont need)

Comment: what if there's something like `1-1-1` you need to match ?

Comment: Try using a word boundary `\b\d+-\d+\b` https://regex101.com/r/Ui8ChD/1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the regex `(\b\d+-\d+\b)`. The `\b` is a word boundary, like a comma, space, start/end of string, etc.

Here's an example: https://www.regexpal.com/?fam=111389

Answer (score 1):

You can apply

```
re.findall(r'(\d+-\d+)', ExampleString)
```

Only mention that information within the group that you want extract

Output

```
['5-10', '48-99', '6-12', '5-9', '4-2']
```